# Grabbing HTML code from URL that needs a delay for webpage to fully load

Tags: html, r

I am trying to use either getURLContent() or HTMLParse() in R to get the html from a website. The issue is that the page loads slowly and in a few chunks.

It seems both of these options stop and return the code after the first chunk of the webpage loads. This leaves the HTML missing a large portion of what would load in another 5-10 seconds.

I need a way to initiate the parse but then have it delay while running to give the page time to load. I have studied the literature on these two options and have not found any option to do that.

Does anyone know if its possible or of a possible work around to this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this problem comes from pages that use Ajax (load the page in several bouts). Hard to tell without more information.

One solution that usually works is to use RSelenium that will mimic a 'real' user by opening up a firefox/explorer/chrome page.

```
# selenium proper
library(RSelenium)
# rvest to convert to xml for easier parsing
library(rvest)

# start a server and open a navigator (firefox by default)
startServer()
driver <- remoteDriver()
driver$open()

# go to google
driver$navigate("http://www.google.com")

# get source code
page <- driver$getPageSource()

# convert to xml for easier parsing
page_xml <- read_html(page[[1]])
```

Comment: Getting the following error. Not sure how to troubleshoot it. Any ideas?

> driver$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Undefined error in RCurl call.
Error in queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session"), "POST", qdata = toJSON(serverOpts))

Comment: Try to run it with chrome instead:, you need to download chromedriver and then startServer(args = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path/chromedriver.exe"))
driver <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
driver$open()